# PHP Function: Return data from loop

Tags: php, arrays, function, loops, return

I want to use a function to load my news feed on my website dynamically from my database, I have created a function with variables for the type of post, from a specific user etc, and I want to run a while() loop to return each and every post as you would usually, how can this be done within a function though? I tried running the loop and setting the content I want to display in a single variable, which it then returns within that loop, I was hoping it would then run a return each time within the loop and the function would echo each out one by one, when I think about it logically, that obviously wouldn't happen, so could someone explain how this would be achieved?

Example (similar) code:

**Accessing the function:**

```
<?php echo getNews(); ?>
```

**The function:**

```
<?php function getNews(){
//query stuff
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
     $return = "Looped data";
     return $return;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return stops function executing. You could try something like

```
function getNews(){
    $html = null;
    //query stuff
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
         $return = "Looped data";
         $html .= $return;
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The return should be used out side of the loop

Try this function

```
<?php function getNews()
{
   $return =array()
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
     $return[] = "Looped data";

   }
   return $return;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the first `return` the function breaks and so only the first row is fetched. You can temporarily save the data in an array and return it. When `echo`ing you can then [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode) it.

```
function getNews(){
    //query stuff
    $result = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
         $result[] = "looped data";
    }
    return $result;
}

echo implode("<br>\n", getNews());
```

Getting an array returned can be more useful in the future. Also the function name is more descriptive in my opinion. It doesn't say concat/etc, only get.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use function to return with each loop. Alternatively either you can save the result created in loop to a variable or an array and return the variable/array. Example using variable is:

```
<?php function getNews() {
    //query stuff
    $return = "";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $return .= "Looped data";    
    }
    return $return;
}
?>
```

If your purpose is just `echo` the result than do it in function itself without using variable. Array would be better if you want to process something with result.